# using list of predefined positions on list in r

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a large and complex list of 10.000 elements and I want to extract only values of a specific position. So, I've made an object only with the positions I want to subset.

```
   index
   [1]    1    3    5    9   18   23   24   25   26   32   37   52   56   57   58   59   60   64   70   72   74   75
```

how I can use only these numbers to extract the elements I want?

I tried something like that, but doesn't work

```
df[[2]][index][[8]][[1]][[1]]

str(df)
.. .. .. ..$ DisorderMappingRelation        :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ Name  :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "BTNT (broader term maps to a narrower term)"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "21541"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
  .. .. .. ..$ DisorderMappingICDRelation     : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ DisorderMappingValidationStatus:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ Name  :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "Validated"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "21611"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
  .. .. .. ..$ .attrs                         : Named chr "3669"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
  .. .. ..$ ExternalReference:List of 6
  .. .. .. ..$ Source                         : chr "OMIM"
  .. .. .. ..$ Reference                      : chr "219900"
  .. .. .. ..$ DisorderMappingRelation        :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ Name  :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "BTNT (broader term maps to a narrower term)"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "21541"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
  .. .. .. ..$ DisorderMappingICDRelation     : NULL
  .. .. .. ..$ DisorderMappingValidationStatus:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ Name  :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "Validated"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "21611"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
  .. .. .. ..$ .attrs                         : Named chr "11886"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
  .. .. ..$ .attrs           : Named chr "7"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "count"
  .. ..$ DisorderDisorderAssociationList:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ text  : chr "\n      "
  .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "0"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "count"
  .. ..$ TextualInformationList         :List of 6
  .. .. ..$ TextualInformation:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ TextSectionList:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ TextSection:List of 3
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ TextSectionType:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ Name  :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "Definition"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "lang"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "16907"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ Contents       : chr "A rare lysosomal disease characterized by an accumulation of cystine inside the lysosomes, causing damage in di"| __truncated__
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs         : Named chr [1:2] "91672" "en"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "id" "lang"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs     : Named chr "1"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "count"
  .. .. .. ..$ .attrs         : Named chr [1:2] "1026" "en"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "id" "lang"
  .. .. ..$ TextualInformation:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ TextSectionList:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "\n          "
  .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "0"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "count"
  .. .. .. ..$ .attrs         : Named chr [1:2] "94635" "en"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "id" "lang"
  .. .. ..$ TextualInformation:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ TextSectionList:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "\n          "
  .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "0"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "count"
  .. .. .. ..$ .attrs         : Named chr [1:2] "74141" "en"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "id" "lang"
  .. .. ..$ TextualInformation:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ TextSectionList:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "\n          "
  .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "0"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "count"
  .. .. .. ..$ .attrs         : Named chr [1:2] "92580" "en"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "id" "lang"
  .. .. ..$ TextualInformation:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ TextSectionList:List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ text  : chr "\n          "
  .. .. .. .. ..$ .attrs: Named chr "0"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "count"
  .. .. .. ..$ .attrs         : Named chr [1:2] "115312" "en"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "id" "lang"
  .. .. ..$ .attrs            : Named chr "5"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "count"
  .. ..$ .attrs                         : Named chr "11"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "id"
```

there are some interest paths to extract values

```
df[[2]][[i]][[3]][[1]]  #Name
df[[2]][[i]][[1]]  #Class
df[[2]][[i]][[8]][[1]][[1]] #Reference 
df[[2]][[i]][[8]][[1]][[2]] #text
```

I want to apply "index" over "i" and extract the values

here is a reproducible and simple example of what I've done

```
a = c("a", "b", "c")
b = c("b", "c", "a")
c = c("d", "a", "b")

lis = c(a,b,c)

df = data.frame(unlist(lapply(1:(length(lis[[1]])), function(i) lis[[1]][[i]][[1]])))
colnames(df) = "names"

index = which(df$names == "a")

lis[[1]][[index]][[1]]
```

with only one element it works, by my real index has near 5.000 numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the 'index' and extract the elements one by one (Without a small example, it is not clear though)

```
sapply(index, function(i) df[[2]][i][[8]][[1]][[1]])
```

Comment: i've edited my post with a reproducible and very simple example

Comment: @bloises do you need `sapply(index, function(i) lis[[1]][[i]][[1]])#
[1] "a"`. Your example is now too simple, so not sure if this would represent your exact case